# How do i replace all nonalphanumeric characters in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all non alphanumeric characters: [^a-zA-Z0-9] to '_'.

I read in php.net that ereg_replace is deprecated. Why is that? Is there a good Perl guide to regular expressions?

How do I achive this with preg_replace function?

Comment: Perl regex tuto: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html more generalist: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_replace` instead.

Try `preg_replace('/\W/', '', $subject)` for replacing all non-word characters inside $subject.

Answer (score 1):

For replacement using a regex pattern, you should use preg_filter, preg_replace or preg_replace_callback. Here are the links to the manuals with sample code.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Link only answer is useless. This should be a comment.

Comment: the question when I answered was "I want to replace all non alphanumeric characters: [^a-zA-Z0-9] to '_'.

@Toto. I read in php.net that ereg_replace is deprecated. Why is that? Is there a good Perl guide to regular expressions?" So I gave links on the functions to use. Did you expect me to read it for them and mind meld my knowledge to the one who answered. Acha utoto Toto